# Get the time by minutes and seconds of each record and then sum the totals

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to get the time by minutes and seconds of each record and then sum the totals

Look at the images of how it is currently and how I would like it to appear.

Thanks

```
DECLARE @TimeInSeconds INT 

SET @TimeInSeconds = (SELECT Datediff(second, Min(lra.time), Max(lra.time)) 
                             segundos 
                      FROM   log_rpa lra 
                      WHERE  1 = 1 
                             AND date = Cast(Getdate() AS DATE) 
                      -- Ejecución hoy 
                      GROUP  BY lra.log_id) 

SELECT lr.log_id, 
       lr.project, 
       Datediff(minute, Min(lr.time), Max(lr.time)) Tiempo_ejecucion_minutos, 
       Datediff(second, Min(lr.time), Max(lr.time)) segundos, 
       (SELECT RIGHT('0' + Cast(@TimeInSeconds / 3600 AS VARCHAR), 2) 
               + ':' 
               + RIGHT('0' + Cast((@TimeInSeconds / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR), 2) 
               + ':' 
               + RIGHT('0' + Cast(@TimeInSeconds % 60 AS VARCHAR), 2)) 
                                                    Tiempo_Ejecucion_exacta 
FROM   log_rpa lr 
WHERE  1 = 1 
GROUP  BY lr.log_id, 
          lr.project, 
          lr.date 
ORDER  BY lr.date DESC
```

[Is so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N81Bh.jpg)

[I need it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xemd6.jpg)

If I need the DurationTime values ​​to be totalled as a sum as it does?

Comment: Output format depends on the type of the date/time column. Check [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fd6e584ea15f11d394f39962f6f780cb) for some links and examples. Changing `convert(time, ...)`  to `convert(time(0), ...)` in my answer should format the output to `HH:MM:SS`.

Comment: Yes, I have already done that part, thank you, and how is that column totaled

Comment: @CamioOrtiz, you should ask _new questions_ instead of updating the same question. That said, for the sum calculation: move (most) of the answer inside a common table expression (CTE) and add `sum()` and formatting: [example fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c795cf3b1436817dffde80dc2e906fe3). Again, create a new question if this example is not sufficient.

Comment: @Sander, many thanks, i don't see every options on the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are stuck on the duration formatting. The `@TimeInSeconds` variable is a constant (its value does not change after the initial `SET`) and therefore produces constant results (`00:05:10`).

The solution below takes the time difference in seconds (`datediff(SS, ...)`) and adds those seconds to an empty `datetime` (equal to `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`, abbreviated like `00:00:00` in the code). Converting this back to the type `time` drops the date part.

**Sample data**

```
create table MyLog
(
  ProjId int,
  LogId int,
  LogDate date,
  LogTime time
);

insert into MyLog (ProjId, LogId, LogDate, LogTime) values
(100, 101, '2020-09-16', '01:00:00'),
(100, 101, '2020-09-16', '01:01:05'), -- project 100, task 101 takes 00:01:05
(100, 102, '2020-09-16', '02:00:00'),
(100, 102, '2020-09-16', '02:05:00'),
(100, 102, '2020-09-16', '02:08:00'); -- project 100, task 102 takes 00:08:00
```

**Solution**

```
select ml.ProjId,
       ml.LogId,
       ml.LogDate,
       min(ml.LogTime) as LogTimeFrom,
       max(ml.LogTime) as LogTimeTo,
       datediff(SS, min(ml.LogTime), max(ml.LogTime)) as DurationSec,
       convert(time, dateadd(SS, datediff(SS, min(ml.LogTime), max(ml.LogTime)), '00:00:00')) as DurationTime
from MyLog ml
group by ml.ProjId,
         ml.LogId,
         ml.LogDate
order by ml.ProjId,
         ml.LogId;
```

**Result**

```
ProjId  LogId  LogDate     LogTimeFrom  LogTimeTo  DurationSec  DurationTime
------- ------ ----------- ------------ ---------- ------------ -------------
100     101    2020-09-16  01:00:00     01:01:05   65           00:01:05
100     102    2020-09-16  02:00:00     02:08:00   480          00:08:00
```

See it in action: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=59c353f19ec98a08e19c06de265d01b3).

Answer (score 0):

I was writing an answer and Sander answered before me! Very similar answers but he was much more succinct.

Only minor issue with Sander's solution (which also exists in the original problem) is the `GROUP BY ml.LogDate`. If a log starts just before midnight and finishes after midnight, you may get two rows - which may have 0 time against them (some other solutions may have negative times e.g., 23:55:00 to 00:05:00 on next day results in -1430)

Instead, I suggest calculating the full datetime e.g., `CAST([ml.LogDate] AS datetime) + CAST([ml.LogTime] AS datetime)` the

- use that for the DATEDIFFs
- use the max (or min) date rather than group by

Here's a version of Sander's code that has been tweaked for the group by date issue

```
select ml.ProjId,
       ml.LogId,
       max(ml.LogDate) AS LogDate,
       min(ml.LogDatetime) as LogTimeFrom,
       max(ml.LogDatetime) as LogTimeTo,
       datediff(SS, min(ml.LogDateTime), max(ml.LogDateTime)) as DurationSec,
       convert(time, dateadd(SS, datediff(SS, min(ml.LogDateTime), max(ml.LogDateTime)), '00:00:00')) as DurationTime
from (select *,  CAST(LogDate AS datetime) + CAST(logTime AS datetime) AS LogDatetime FROM MyLog) ml
group by ml.ProjId,
         ml.LogId
order by ml.ProjId,
         ml.LogId;
```

And here's the tweak on Sander's fiddle, with an additional log crossing midnight: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8ab22b84a3dca9b184d9d2851ba4f12c)